# Spring Security SAML Extension with Remember Me functionality across multiple tomcat webapps

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have 2 spring applications that are running side by side on a tomcat server. I am using the token based RememberMeAuthenticationProvider with a custom UserDetailsService so I only authenticate the users once and they can navigate between the 2 applications without having to reauthenticate.

Along with the normal username/password login process I have configured the spring saml extension to authenticate users on my application (SP) using an external IdP. I use the SAMLAuthenticationProvider with a custom SAMLUserDetailsService to match the saml assertion username to a user in my database and they are authenticated in **one** of my applications. The problem I am having is the user is not authenticated on my second application. It keeps asking for a username and password when navigating to the second application, as I would expect because there is no remember me token/cookie configured for the SAMLAuthenticationProvider.

Is there any way I can use token based remember me services with the SAMLUserDetailsService?

Answer (score 0):

have you configured both apps to use the same session store? are they on the same domain/subdomain so they can share the auth cookie? i would set one of the apps to be the (only) auth point and set the login from the second to go to it for auth.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the SAMLAuthenticationProvider and manually creating a remember me token (by copying spring source code under the RememberMeAuthenticationProvider) when a user successfully authenticates.

I couldn't find a way to elegantly combine the features of the SAMLAuthenticationProvider and the RememberMeAuthenticationProvider through spring configuration, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to ensure `SAMLProcessingFilter.rememberMeServices` has been set.
This is a little tricky because none of the default `rememberMe()` components are exposed. Here's a possible solution.

```
@Autowired
public void configureRememberMe(
        @Qualifier(BeanIds.SPRING_SECURITY_FILTER_CHAIN) Filter securityChain,
        List<SAMLProcessingFilter> filters
) {
    RememberMeServices rememberMe = ((FilterChainProxy) securityChain).getFilterChains().stream()
            .flatMap(chain -> chain.getFilters().stream())
            .filter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class::isInstance)
            .map(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.class::cast)
            .findAny()
            .map(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter::getRememberMeServices)
            .orElseGet(NullRememberMeServices::new);

    filters.forEach(filter -> filter.setRememberMeServices(rememberMe));
}
```

If you construct your own `RememberMeServices` then just inject it directly rather than fishing it out of the filter chain.

Next problem is if you don't have `.alwaysRemember()`. I don't think there's any way to pass a request parameter through an IdP. You're going to have to either extend a `RememberMeServices` and override `rememberMeRequested` based on some external context, or extend `WebSSOProfile` to add the remember-me parameter dynamically to the binding URLs.